# Making a double click event work only when clicked on specific datagrid row?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

I currently have a datagrid that I am binding to a method within my xaml's .cs file. The goal is to be able to double click a given row, and it does a task. However, I do not want the user to be able to call the function by clicking a row, then double click wherever else on the datagrid. I would like the user to only be able to call the function when double clicking on a given row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough info to answer this question. Are you wanting to use a event handler in the code-behind? Or an ICommand handler in the item itself? The latter is what you should be using, but since you haven't tagged MVVM I'll assume the former.

The problem is you need to set an EventSetter on the DataRow style, but EventSetters can't be set with DataTriggers, so you need to set it on *all* of them and do your filtering in the handler (there are ways around this, but it starts getting convoluted at which point you're better off just switching to MVVM). Declare your DataGrid and set the event handler via the RowStyle:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Then in the handler do your check:

```
private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var row = sender as DataGridRow;
    var dataElement = row?.DataContext as MyItem;
    if (dataElement?.CanDoubleClick != true)
        return;

    // process double-click here
    return;
}
```